# Change start / end points of a line with field attributes

Tags: qgis

I've written an expression to update node layers coordinates to coordinate values from a survey file with the following expression:

`geom_from_wkt('POINT('||$x||' '||$y||' '||$z||')')`

(replacing `$x`, `$y` and `$z` with the field names of the northing, easting and elevation values)  This works great for moving the nodes to the proper coordinates.

Now I'm trying to use the same logic to update the start and end points of a line layer but I can't seem to get the proper syntax, what I was expecting to work is:

`geom_from_wkt('start_point('||$x||' '||$y||')')`

`geom_from_wkt('end_point('||$x||' '||$y||')')`

(again, replacing `$x` and `$y` with the attribute field names)

I'm not getting any errors, but the geometry is also not updating... I can only assume the expression is not written correctly? or is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `start_point` only works with `geometry` of lines and `geom_from_wkt` only with `wkt-geometry`. Shouldnt it rather be something like `start_point(geom_from_wkt('Linestring('||"x1"||' '||"y1"||','||"x2"||' '||"y2"||')'))`? Still not really sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: Where are you inputting your expression?

Comment: I'm working on a pipe network, it's made of a line vector layer for pipes and a node vector layer for manholes, I've updated the node layer coordinates (as mentioned above) with the actual surveyed values from the field work so that the nodes are in the correct locations, no I want to be able to update the start and end coordinates of the lines so that they match the manhole coordinates.  My line records have upstream/downstream manholes identified and I'm joining the tables so that I have the upstream (start) coordinates and downstream (end) coordinates available in the line layer.

Comment: I'm inputting my expression in the field calculator, I've selected 'update existing field' and choosen 'geometry'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update your line geometry, an expression like `geom_from_wkt('Linestring('||"x1"||' '||"y1"||','||"x2"||' '||"y2"||')')` should do it. In case you only want a point layer of start and end points to be updated use `start_point(geom_from_wkt('Linestring('||"x1"||' '||"y1"||','||"x2"||' '||"y2"||')'))` respecitvely `end_point()`.

To get the attributes / geometry from your node layer to your line layer you need a matching field (id or similar) and use something like `x(geometry(get_feature('yournodelayername','matchingfield_of_nodelayer',attribute($currentfeature,'matchingfield_of_linelayer')))))`

Comment: geom_from_wkt('Linestring('||"x1"||' '||"y1"||','||"x2"||' '||"y2"||')') was exactly what I was looking for.  I haven't worked with geom_from_wkt much, so I didn't quite understand the syntax - makes sense now though.  Thanks for the great answer